# How can I debug objects on XCode the same way I do in Eclipse?

Tags: xcode, debugging, nsobject

I'd like to see the content of NSObjects like properties ( arrays, Integers, floats... ). Since I'm a Flex developer I'm used to use the eclipse debugging tool. But now I'm starting with the iPhone I'm kind of lost.

For example, I just downloaded the SeismicXML application from the dev's sample code, and I put a breakpoint on the connectionDidFinishLoading and parseEarthquakeData methods.

I'd like to print the data ( the xml ) but I don't know how.

THe only thing I could achieve is to print the object using the po command on the gdb.

Any idea?

Note: XCode 4 and above has improved the debugging system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the visual property viewer doesn't seem to be as nice as I'd like.  I spend a good chunk of my time in the gdb console issuing all kinds of crazy print statements.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I debug objects on XCode

On the top left of XCode you can see a drop down menu, make sure to choose "Debug" as the Active config.
Put your breakpoints then open Debuuger (from Run menu)
You should see something like this  [image]
<sub>(source: [cocoalab.com](http://www.cocoalab.com/media/becomeanxcoder/05/08_debugger.png))</sub>

As you can see there is step buttons just like Eclipse.

> I'd like to print the data ( the xml ) but I don't know how.

Do you mean printing it to Console? like while tracing?
In that case, you can use `NSLog(NSString *string);`